# How to make list-items into javascript array

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have a variable which contains some HTML. This HTML is not on the document body - only in the variable! From this, I want to extract the contents of each `li` and put it into an array, so that I can make something new with each list item.

Can I do something like this?

```
var myList = "<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>";
myList.getElementByTagName('LI') = myLiContents;
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy element and set the `innerHTML` of that element as the HTML string you have:

```
var myList = "<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>",
    dummy = document.createElement('div');

dummy.innerHTML = myList;
console.log(dummy.getElementsByTagName('li'));
```

Note however that the result of `getElementsByTagName` is **not** an array, but a [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList), an array-like object. You can still run a loop through the `nodeList` to create a real array though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `getElementByTagName` on a string... only on HTML elements inserted into the document. But for what you're trying to achieve, you don't really need to do that. You can use a regexp to extract all the `<li>`s from your string:

```
var li = myList.match(/<li>.*?<\/li>/gi);
```

Which will produce an array like this:

```
["<li>item 1</li>", "<li>item 2</li>", "<li>item 3</li>"]
```

To get rid of the extra `<li>` and `</li>` you can do a string replace as you're looping through each item:

```
li[i].replace(/<\/?li>/gi, "");
```